# Custom error message in subpanel suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Im trying to figure out how to add a custom error message in subpanel quick create if a record does note exist. 
Im new with suitecrm, is this possible ? ive tried with a logic hook but it only appears in the module itself but not in the subpanel.

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question like how you want to check record existence? When the error message needs to be triggered etc etc